# Synchronize a method over different instances of an Object

Tags: java, synchronization

I have a class:

```
class Station {
  public void decrement(){
    // ...      
  }
}
```

There are two different instances of it: **station1** and **station2**. The function **decrement()** gets called on **station1** and **station2** by two different threads. I want to synchronize `decrement()` over all objects and threads.

As per what I read, `synchronized` keyword synchronizes the calls of a function of one single object, so it won't work here. How do I synchronize calls across all instances of `Station`?

Comment: You could synchronize on the class using: `synchronized(Station.class)` or using a `private static final Object MUTEX = new Object()` and then synchronizing on that object

Answer (score 2):

`synchronized` object instead. Example:

```
class Station {
    private final static Object DECREMENT_LOCKER = new Object();

    public void decrement(){
        synchronized (DECREMENT_LOCKER) {
            //do smt
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks got it. So when we simply use synchronized keyword for a function. Does that also synchronize on some object ?